# Injecting a dependency having constructor parameters in common with the higher level class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Sometimes when I design my classes, I need some dependency classes with similar constructor parameters. Assume we have

```
interface IDependency {
    void DoSomething();
}

class DependencyClass : IDependency {
    public DependencyClass(int length) {...}
    ...
}

class MainClass {
    public MainClass(int length, IDependency dependency) {...}
    ...
}
```

`MainClass` needs an instance of `DependencyClass` with the same `length`. I have two methods in mind to deal with it:

1. Not creating instances of `MainClass` directly and always getting them from a factory. This way I can make sure that the desired `IDependency` instance will be provided to `MainClass` constructor.
2. Passing a factory interface, say `IDependencyFactory`, to `MainClass` constructor instead of `IDependency`. So that I can get the desired instance of `DependencyClass` within my `MainClass` implementation.

I'm not sure if either of them is a good choice. Is there a best practice in this case?

Comment: Interesting question! Are you looking for a generic design solution or can it be specific to a DI framework?

Comment: Can you consider make `length` a parameter in of the `MainClass` method, which will use it?

Comment: @Flater A generic solution would be great.

Comment: I think you are looking for something like the builder pattern, where you can build in one function let's say a one type of pizza (large pizza with extra cheese), or another type of pizza ( small pizza with extra cheese), please have a look at builder pattern, and also decorator pattern.

Comment: @Fabio No, it must be known at object creation time to let the class do some initializations.

Comment: _it must be known at object creation time to let the class do some initializations_ - perfect candidate for a factory pattern.

Comment: If `length` is a _runtime value_, you should refrain from injecting it into a injection constructor. [Injecting runtime values into components is a code-smell](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: @Gilad I looked at them. As I understood, **builder** pattern is used to create specific instances of classes. So in my case it is something like having `BuilderForLength1`, `BuilderForLength2`, ... classes which doesn't make sense.  **Decorator** pattern on the other hand, is used for extending a class. But actually I'm not going to extend any class, I'm just going to use a `IDependency` to do a responsibility.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very interesting question and the answer lies in what you try to achieve here.

**Solution 1.** you provided will make your `IDependency`  the main factory interface, all instanced will be implemented with `IDependency` interface which will provide you with a lot of scalability - you will be able to use the `IDependency` interface to initialize additional classes in the future with different functionality, which is the classic use and implementation of factory design pattern.

**solution 2.**  you provided will make your `MainClass` well, the Main Class of the program, you will handle the instances and their behavior inside the main class and the advantage here is that you can manage all of your instances through `IDependency`, and the only thing you do in `MainClass` is handle their logic, `MinaClass` will be your instances transporter and all of the fundamental changes for the base classes will be made in the interface `IDependency` which is a classic solution for **Dependency Inversion**.

The question still remains, what you are trying to achieve. Consider this question and the two possibilities and you have your answer.

Comment: Nice comment ;)

Answer (score 4):

If your `length` is runtime variable - refer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51817115/injecting-a-dependency-having-constructor-parameters-in-common-with-the-higher-l#comment90589928_51817115).

If you need this in runtime, you can use the solution #2 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51817415/4069913).

If it's compile time setting, you can inject it as any other dependency, that's normal that both `MainClass` and `DependencyClass` are dependent on the same value.

To have a safe compile-time injection, you can introduce something like that:

```
interface ILength {
    int Length { get; }
}

class StaticLength : ILength {
    public StaticLength(int length) {
        Length = length;
    }
}

void Main() {
    const int length = 10;
    ILength lengthDependency = new StaticLength(length);
    IDependency dep = new DependencyClass(lengthDependency);
    MainClass mainClass = new MainClass(lengthDependency, dep); 
}
```

And now you can implement any kind of `ILength` - read from configuration file, constant, web, mock, calculate base on any other dependency, random etc.

Answer (score 4):

One of the simplest changes you could make to guarantee the length will be the same for both the `DepencyClass` and the `MainClass` is to add a `Length` property to the interface and initialize it from a constructor, and then allow `MainClass` to access the length (you then save one parameter on the `MainClass`, which is more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

```
interface IDependency {
    int Length { get; }
    void DoSomething();
}

class DependencyClass : IDependency {
public DependencyClass(int length) { Length = length; }
    ...
}

class MainClass {
    public MainClass(IDependency dependency) {...}
    ...
    // do something with dependency.Length
}
```

This does have the possible drawback of "polluting" your interface and perhaps exposing the length to other code. That's up to you if that matters.